# How to find out on which collection permission errors happens

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, firebase-security

I have an application using Angular + AngularFire + Firestore. I didn't have any security rules before, now I tried to add security rules. and I added the below, it means if user is not loggedIn he can't read or write.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null ;
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried it in my app, when I logout the application I get 3 errors like below, I want to find the collection cause the issue then change my rules, but all happens in vendor.js and core.js and no useful information.

Any Idea how to track down the issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you log in before hitting on firebase with AngularFireAuth or Firebase Auth?

Comment: @HassanAli this happens after logout (so it seems since my angular services kept alive after logout they still subscribing to firebase)

Comment: Instead of showing screenshots of text, please copy the text into the question itself, so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages at runtime aren't going to indicate anything about the query that failed. This is for security reasons - a potential attacker should be given no information about what exactly they did wrong. You're going to have to look though your code and find the places where your app is making unauthenticated requests.

Comment: is there any debug mode or something?

Comment: Not in production, no.  The local emulator will give you more output, but that won't be running against your app, just your test code.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent tool available on the rules tab in the database section.  There, you can construct a simulated request and run it.  If you're searching for a collection, try several requests, one for each collection.

If a request is unsuccessful, you'll be shown an error message as well as the line in your rules which triggered the failure. To use this tool, click on the icon circled here...

[image]

Once there, you can construct a request matching your test code.  There's a switch on that tab called "Authenticated".  Turn that on to reveal an authentication form.  Go to the Authentication tab (lefthand nav) and copy a UID from one of your users.  Back on the simulator tab, paste that UID in the authentication form.

Comment: thanks for answer, I know that all of my collections are secure and when I try that simulator it approves that, my question is my application still tries to read from firebase, to exclude that collection I need to know the name, but in the error message there is no trace about what collection it was

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  I think I understand now that you're trying to debug the code, not your rules.  Does your code accessing various collections include error handling?  Therein, you can log which collection was being accessed.  (Or am I still misunderstanding?)

Comment: No sweat! There are 10 collections and used in various services, I tried to add `tap` in `pipe` to find out which one is that, but the error happens before reaching to `tap`, so I updated my rules and added all collections with `read true` except one collection, and that collection is source of one of the issues, now I am investigating why my service is still reading from that

Comment: Okay.  Sounds like you're on the trail.  If you're unable to solve it, consider editing your question to include the code, structure, what collection you think is being read first, second, third, etc, how you catch and log errors, and so on.  Debugging code is how to look for this problem.